# Firebase realtime database doesnt display values on my website

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, esp8266

I'm facing an issue with firebase where it displays values on my website but only when I input them manually. But when my esp8266 publishes data to firebase the data can't be read by my website. It just says null. The value and the type is the same as the esp one but it only shows when I create it. And the value from the esp is just written again so then 2 values with the same name show up. The firebaseConfig is empty for security reasons.

Thanks for any help in advance!

This is my javascript code:

```
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.2/firebase-app.js";
import { getDatabase, ref, onValue } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.2/firebase-database.js";

// Initialize Firebase with your configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "",
    measurementId: ""
  };

  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);



// Reference to your data in the database
// Reference to your data in the database for Humidity 3x1 and Humidity 4x1
var humidity3x1Ref = ref(getDatabase(), "Humidity3x1");
var humidity4x1Ref = ref(getDatabase(), "Humidity4x1");

// Get the data and update the HTML for Humidity 3x1
onValue(humidity3x1Ref, function(snapshot) {
    var dataValue = snapshot.val();
    var pathElement = document.querySelector(".circular-chart.orange .circle");
    var textElement = document.querySelector(".circular-chart.orange .percentage");
    
    // Update the circular chart and percentage text
    updateCircularChart(pathElement, textElement, dataValue);
});

// Get the data and update the HTML for Humidity 4x1
onValue(humidity4x1Ref, function(snapshot) {
    var dataValue = snapshot.val();
    var pathElement = document.querySelector(".circular-chart.green .circle");
    var textElement = document.querySelector(".circular-chart.green .percentage");
    
    // Update the circular chart and percentage text
    updateCircularChart(pathElement, textElement, dataValue);
});

// Function to update circular chart and percentage text
function updateCircularChart(pathElement, textElement, dataValue) {
    pathElement.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", `${dataValue}, 100`);
    textElement.textContent = `${dataValue}%`;
}
```

Comment: The code looks fine at first glance. Stack Overflow is a notoriously inefficient interactive debugger, so it's best if you debug locally and tell us the result of that. So: If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have properly configured security rules on firebase admin portal - https://console.firebase.google.com.

From your description, it seems that you are allowing access only to the data that is owned/created by the specific user.